# Capture USB scanner buttons with Wireshark

Tags: usb, wireshark, scanner, sane

I want to detect if buttons on my USB scanner (HP Scanjet 8250) are pressed using Debian Linux.

I'm able to scan documents with SANE but I cannot get scanbd/scannerbutton working.

Now I found out that as a workaround I could capture USB traffic using Wireshark 2.0.2 (Linux kernel version: 4.4.0-45) c. But a first test was not successful: I can see traffic when a document is scanned, but I cannot see any traffic if scanner buttons are pressed.

Is it possible at all to detect USB scanner buttons with Wireshark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you would not be able to see the button presses on your scanner.  Wireshark can monitor USB traffic on the USB bus, if properly configured.  The buttons on your scanner are probably not sending keypresses over the USB bus, but being handled by an internal microcontroller in the scanner, which sends *data* over the USB bus to the scanner driver.  In Windows, the scanner's buttons are configured by the manufacturer's scanning software.  However, if there is no equivalent Linux software to handle the configuration, you are most likely out of luck.